# compact and normal operator is diagonlisable

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

My question is regarding this post : [compact and normal operator is diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489175/compact-and-normal-operator-is-diagonalizable#comment9186435_1489191), there is a detail in the argument that I don't understand why is $u(K^{\perp}) \subseteq K^{\perp}$ ?

Comment: I think I found the answer : $K$ is reduced by $u$ since $K$ is invariant by $u$ and $u^*$

Comment: @AnneBauval $K$ is reduced by $u$ means that both $K$ and $K^{\perp}$ are invariant by $u$, this would follow from the fact that $K$ is invariant by $u$ as well as $u^*$

Comment: @AnneBauval To see why take any $x \in K^{\perp}$ and any $y \in K$ then $ (u(x),y)=(x,u^*(y))=0$ since $K$ is invariant by $u^*$

Comment: Perfect. This is why I told you that the key point was  "$K$
 is invariant by $u^∗$" ($K$ invariant by $u$ is useless here). But now, are you able to prove this crucial point, or is it precisely for this that you need help? (This was my question.)

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks, I only needed help for this, the rest of the proof is straightforward.

Comment: Since you only need help for this,  the following post answers your question: [Eigenvectors for normal operators and their adjoints](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879816/386889).

Comment: @user715747 could you plz explain why K is invariant by $u^*$ ? I'm actually searching for a proof that any invariant subspace of a compact normal operator $T$ actually reduce $T$. This post is the closest one I found.

Comment: @Westlifer Here, $K$ is not *any* invariant subspace. It is the closure of a subspace spanned by eigenvectors for the compact normal operator $u$. In the link in the closure banner, it is proved that if $u(e)=\lambda e$ then $u^*(e)=\bar\lambda e$. This proves that $K$ is invariant by $u^*$. As for your problem, if $K$ is invariant by some normal operator $T$ then the restriction of $T$ to $K$ is still normal hence (by the spectral theorem for such operators) you can apply the previous argument.

Comment: @AnneBauval I've noticed that and figured it out. Many thanks!